# Get data from MySQL table field as JSON in php

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest

I get the data from mysql.Got json format, but I need the custom key value.

```
$format = 'json';

$query = "select id,name,description,appIcon from assets";

$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

$posts = array();

if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {

    while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $posts[] = $post;
    }

}

if ($format == 'json') 
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($posts);
}
```

The result is:

```
[{"id": "58", "name": "Ashok", "description": "good person", "appIcon": "1.jpg"}]
```

but I need this:

```
[{"cus_id":"58", "cus_name":"Ashok", "details": "good person", "image": "1.jpg"}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help you solve your problem - but nobody is going to write code for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Replace your SQL `$query = "select id,name,description,appIcon from assets";`

with following & execute once.

```
$query = "select id as cus_id,name as cus_name,description as details,appIcon as image from assets";
```

Comment: nice usage of MySQLs aliases :)

Comment: @Ashok Please accept the answer, If it has solved your problem. :)